# Using Regex replace all occurences of string within VQMod

Tags: php, regex, vqmod, opencart2.3

I am building an extension for Opencart 2.3.x and I need to replace all occurences of `DIR_IMAGE` with `_DIR_IMAGE` , so I came up with this regular expression that works with PHP alone, but not within a VQMod mod:

```
<operation error="log">
    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[/(.*?)(DIR_IMAGE)(.*?)/g]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[$1_DIR_IMAGE$3]]></add>
</operation>
```

This PHP-only does work:

```
preg_replace('/(.*?)(DIR_IMAGE)(.*?)/g', '$1_DIR_IMAGE$3', $string);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? At this point I assume alternatives to the expression above are appreciated.

Comment: PHP regex does not support the `g` modifier. `preg_replace` by default replaces all non-overlapping occurrences. Besdies, you need to use `regex="true"` to be able to use a regex. `<search regex="true">`

Comment: @AD7six because I am using VQMod, which is a thirdparty piece of code to override original files. It is the only way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried with ~exp~ to no avail, and also /exp/

Comment: Add the regex attribute and retry - `<search regex="true">`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you were right, I forgot the regex attr, I rarely use it so I didnt even remembered .. Please write down your answer so I can mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to tell the engine to use a regex with `regex=true` attribute.

Another issue is that `g` is not supported by PHP `preg_replace`, it replaces all occurrences by default.

Besides, you do not need the groups because `.*?` do not restrict the context (a hint: the `.*?` at the end of the pattern *never* matches anything, its group value is always an empty string because it is lazy and is not even tried), you may just use

```
<search regex="true" position="replace"><![CDATA[/DIR_IMAGE/]]></search>
<add><![CDATA[_DIR_IMAGE]]></add>
```

Note that a regex will make more sense if you need to restrict the context where you match `DIR_IMAGE`. If you need to match `DIR_IMAGE` that is not already preprended with `_` use

```
<search regex="true" position="replace"><![CDATA[/(?<!_)DIR_IMAGE/]]></search>
                                                  ^^^^^^
```

Since you are using a CDATA block, there is no need to entitize `<` in the negative lookbehind `(?<!_)` that fails the match if there is `_` immediately to the left of the current location.

Comment: Don't know how to this applies to the op but the regex `/\bDIR_IMAGE\b/` (i.e. using word boundaries) is more appropriate than using capturing groups.

Comment: @AD7six That is possible, but we do not have  the actual requirements. Sure, word boundaries may restrict the matches and will make using a regex more sensible. I added a regex that will only match those `DIR_IMAGE`s that have no `_` immediately preceding the `DIR_IMAGE` substring.